# Appengine PHP Fatal error The request was aborted

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a storage application that runs on google appengine using php. By default Appengine allows 60 seconds for each frontend request to complete its execution otherwise it timeout the request. I have a webservice which return public urls of a given directory. I am getting following exception when exceuting the script incase there are a lot files in the directory (around 300 files)

> PHP Fatal error:  The request was aborted because it exceeded the
>   maximum execution time. in
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RealApiProxy.php
>   on line 50 PHP Fatal error:  The request was aborted because it
>   exceeded the maximum execution time. in
>   /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/log/LogService.php
>   on line 413

I have read documentation that App engine timeout requests that take more than 60 seconds? What should i do in my case? Ay help in this regard will be higly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run the request on a [module configured for manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/#PHP_Instance_scaling_and_class) in order to get around the 60 second limit.